# Is there a way to make the Limit value interactive in MongoDB c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, unity-game-engine, bson

I am wondering if there is a way to make the Limit() variable changeable when the application is running?
Here is my code:

```
    void Start()
    {
        m_ButtonRun.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }
    public void TaskOnClick() //
    {
        string connectionString = "myconnection";

        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase("mydb");
        //var database = server.GetDatabase("WIVEmydbData");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("mycollection");
        var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending("Time");

        var document = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Sort(sort).Limit(limit: 1).ForEachAsync(d => Console.WriteLine(d));
        Console.WriteLine(document.ToString());

        //streamwriter writes the Console.WriteLine to multi-import.txt
        FileStream filestream = new FileStream("import.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        var writeFile = new StreamWriter(filestream);
        {
            writeFile.AutoFlush = true;
            Console.SetOut(writeFile);
            writeFile.Write(document.ToString());
        }
}
```

Is it possible to assign a public Button to increasing the limit by 1 for example somehow?
My idea is to have 3 buttons: "increase limit", "execute the DB search", "decrease Limit". The execute part works perfectly, just wondering if it's possible at all to make the Limit() customized on the fly.

Edit:
Added the complete code... oh boy
What I thought about was to put something like an X in the () of the Limit(), set the X to be a default of 1 and then have two buttons to add or subtract 1 from the X value.

Comment: Could you add a bit more code for context? what hinders you from using different values for the limit in different methods and use these in the different buttons?

Comment: I want to be able to change the Limit() via buttons in the user interface. It would make the application much more neat since I already send the data request via a button.

Comment: Well as said please add more code to show how exactly this line is used ... also as said .. what hinders you from using `var document = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Sort(sort).Limit(limit: 1).ForEachAsync(d => Console.WriteLine(d));` in one button and `var document = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Sort(sort).Limit(limit: 2).ForEachAsync(d => Console.WriteLine(d));` from another button? Or from using a field `int limitValue;` in(/de)crease via buttons and use `var document = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Sort(sort).Limit(limitValue).ForEachAsync(d => Console.WriteLine(d));`?

Comment: added the code... The limitValue part got me thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments I'm pretty sure you could simply do something like

```
[SerializeField] Button increaseButton;
[SerializeField] Button decreaseButton;

private void Start()
{
    m_ButtonRun.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    increaseButton.onClick.AddListener(IncreaseLimit);
    decreaseButton.onClick.AddListener(DecreaseLimit);
}

private int limit = 1;

public void IncreaseLimit()
{
    limit++;
}

public void DecreaseLimit()
{
    limit--;

    limit = Mathf.Max(limit, 1);
}

public void TaskOnClick() //
{
    string connectionString = "myconnection";

    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var database = client.GetDatabase("mydb");
    //var database = server.GetDatabase("WIVEmydbData");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("mycollection");
    var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending("Time");

    var document = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Sort(sort).Limit(limit).ForEachAsync(d => Console.WriteLine(d));
    Console.WriteLine(document.ToString());

    //streamwriter writes the Console.WriteLine to multi-import.txt
    FileStream filestream = new FileStream("import.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    var writeFile = new StreamWriter(filestream);
    {
        writeFile.AutoFlush = true;
        Console.SetOut(writeFile);
        writeFile.Write(document.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a legend! Thanks again, I've been jumping between 3 different scripts for the past days and fine tuning them to work together well enough so my brain started to melt. Also there is a reason why I chose this name... heh.